Live or Extract in Tableau?
I am new to Tableau and am currently working on a case study, I am using Tableau 21.4 and I have the dataset on my system. Also I need to share the file over mail and the receiver should be able to read the file. In this case should I go in for a Live or extract connection?
I have tried to test it by opening the file using Tableau Public and it says Data Source is not an extract. As per my knowledge the receiver has a licensed version of Tableau but I am not sure if it will throw the same error.

If your data is static and rarely updated, use an extract.
I would suggest reading the documentation on both of these as they have their own unique pros and cons. Check out this article on the matter.
